Failed to resolve: com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0-appcompat
Recently I switched to Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 1, however after switching I'm facing below 4 error messages during project sync.
Failed to resolve: com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0-appcompat
Show in Project Structure dialog
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Failed to resolve: com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation-java:1.2.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Failed to resolve: com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Failed to resolve: com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Show Details
Affected Modules: app



How much I try, nothing is working out. Can you plesae help me to fix this issue. My codes are as below:

build.gradle (Module)
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}


android {
    namespace 'com.project.localshop'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.localshop"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 30
        versionName "3.30.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.8.6'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.6'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.8.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.15.0'

    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.13.0-alpha07'

    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.3.0'

    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:6.0.0"
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.8.0'

    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.4.0")
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.4.0'

    implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0-appcompat'
    implementation 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation-java:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
}


build.gradle(Project)
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.7.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.7.1' apply false
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.1' apply false
}

settings.gradle
import org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.RepositoriesMode

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.cashfree.com/release' }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "localshop"
include ':app'

I tried adding jcenter() in settings.gradle file, but it seems it's deprecated now and new version is mavenCentral() which I've already added.

All of the dependencies you have mentioned have not been maintained in a long time.

com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0-appcompat was last released in 2020

https://github.com/oneHamidreza/MeowBottomNavigationJava was last released in 2020

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator was last updated 12 years ago

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper was last updated 6 years ago


Since JCenter has been going into sunset publishers of those libraries need to migrate them to MavenCentral.
If they have not done so, you won't be able to use them.
Your options are to:

Clone the repositories and work on them so they are up to date with the current API levels
Find more recent alternative libraries that help you do what you are after


Thank you very much for your reply. Just need few more info...


Clone the repositories and work on them so they are up to date with the current API levels - How to clone and keep them up to date with current APIs ? Isn't choosing alternative libraries a better option ?


Find more recent alternative libraries that help you do what you are after - Any new suggestions from your end for these 4 old libraries ?



@NareshPradhan - 1. You can clone the libraries by forking them in GitHub. 2. I don't have any suggestions since I am not familiar with all these libraries. I believe a short Google search/Chat GPT can help here.
If my answer helped you, please mark it as such and upvote it so others can find it more easily.

Done. Thanks again for all your time and support. Have a good time ahead !

@NareshPradhan - Glad to help.
